# SAGA version issue in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, saga

While running SAGA 7.30 version in QGIS 3.16, they show an error that version is not supporting and checking about a new version for up-gradation that might solve the issue but the 7.30 version is the newest.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's doable, you'll need the SAGA Next Gen plugin to use SAGA 7.3. See the last few postings in this thread:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-and-SAGA-7-3-0-td5447976.html

Comment: I follow the same procedure to solve the issues but still hasn't solved, I think it's due to the ubuntu 20.04 version

Comment: That's what I'm using. Which SAGA algorithm are you trying to use?

Comment: Fill and sink from Terrain-Analysis Hydrology but I see this error for all algorithms

Comment: The link osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-and-SAGA-7-3-0-td5447976.html 
 is now: https://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg46350.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAGA 'Fill sinks' algorithm works here in QGIS 3.16.0 running in Ubuntu 20.04 with SAGA version 7.3.0. It throws a warning but not an error and the result appears to be fine. Try the following:

Firstly, in the Processing Toolbox options deactivate SAGA.

Secondly, install the QGIS plugin 'Processing Saga NextGen Provider'.

Thirdly, in the Processing Toolbox options under SAGANG, set the 'SAGA folder' to '/usr/bin'.

At this stage try running the 'Fill sinks' algorithm, if it doesn't work let us know what error messages are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the same issue.
Actually the current SAGA version is 7.8.1 (see here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%207/SAGA%20-%207.8.1/), but it has not yet made it to the ubuntu repositories. There is a tar.gz to download from the saga folder for linux distros, though I have not managed to get it to run on ubuntu 20.04, but maybe you have better luck (or someone else here can help us on this).

My workaround for now:

- Most SAGA modules actually work in QGIS even though the warning message about the outdated SAGA version is displayed.
- If the SAGA module doesn't work in QGIS I open SAGA and execute it there. SAGA is not the most user friendly app, but the modules work well.

Comment: An update: With some outside help I managed to compile SAGA 7.8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and connected it to QGIS.... and there is no real improvement. The error message changes slightly ("SAGA version 7.8.1 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues") and it appears the same SAGA algorithms encounter the same issues (some work, some don't...).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to all SAGA vector algorithms that works!

The next model is an example for SAGA *Convert Polygons to Lines* algorithm. Just change this algorithm with the one you need (plus the necessary inputs).

[image]