# Getting an error when using Natural neighbour (QGIS 3.16 Hannover)

Tags: qgis, error, saga

I am having trouble with the following: For a project I need a topographic map with contour lines of a specific area. I've googled around and the only suitable option (without buying expensive software subscriptions) I could find was using QGIS. I am running Version 3.16.1 Hannover.

I followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/aJm9lewzooU?t=274 (Time Stamp 4:34)

I created a raster using the path option in Google Earth Pro and then added elevation data from http://gpsvisualizer.com/elevation, downloaded that as a CSV and imported it through Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer. No problems until here.

But when I try to run the natural neighbour tool I always get the same error, no matter what I do:

```
QGIS version: 3.16.1-Hannover QGIS code revision: 3ecbe06f78 Qt version: 5.14.2 GDAL version: 3.1.2 GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3 PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020 
  SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues

Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Natural neighbour' starting… 
  Input parameters: { 'FIELD' : 'altitude (m)', 'METHOD' : 1, 'SHAPES' : 'delimitedtext://file:///Users/nico/Desktop/PDC/qgis%20test/contour.txt?type=csv&delimiter=%5Ct&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'TARGET_OUT_GRID' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'TARGET_TEMPLATE' : None, 'TARGET_USER_FITS' : 0, 'TARGET_USER_SIZE' : 0.0005, 'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX' : '-8.454885447,-8.451031086,41.837634791,41.839088587 [EPSG:4326]', 'WEIGHT' : 0 }

grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "/private/var/folders/0v/y9l9kz9d4jsd8brqmj4z4_mr0000gn/T/processing_zaDUCh/35053aaf34db4508b33b526507c834a0/SHAPES.shp"
-FIELD "altitude (m)" -METHOD 1 -TARGET_USER_XMIN -8.454885447 -TARGET_USER_XMAX -8.451031086 -TARGET_USER_YMIN 41.837634791 -TARGET_USER_YMAX 41.839088587 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.0005 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -WEIGHT 0.0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "/private/var/folders/0v/y9l9kz9d4jsd8brqmj4z4_mr0000gn/T/processing_zaDUCh/c71189e2b98047a680f774f0920ce824/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat"
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0

Unknown option 'SHAPES'
library path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/ library name: libgrid_gridding library : grid_gridding tool : Natural Neighbour identifier : 3 author : O.Conrad (c) 2008
____________________________

Usage: saga_cmd grid_gridding 3 [-POINTS <str>] [-FIELD <str>] [-TARGET_DEFINITION <str>] [-TARGET_USER_SIZE <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_COLS <num>] [-TARGET_USER_ROWS <num>] [-TARGET_USER_FITS <str>] [-TARGET_TEMPLATE <str>] [-TARGET_OUT_GRID <str>] [-METHOD <str>] [-WEIGHT <double>]  
-POINTS:<str> Points Shapes (input)  
-FIELD:<str> Attribute Table field  
-TARGET_DEFINITION:<str> Target Grid System Choice Available Choices: [0] user defined [1] grid or grid system Default: 0  
-TARGET_USER_SIZE:<double> Cellsize Floating point Minimum: 0.000000 Default: 1.000000  
-TARGET_USER_XMIN:<double> West Floating point Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMAX:<double> East Floating point Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMIN:<double> South Floating point Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMAX:<double> North Floating point Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_COLS:<num> Columns Integer Minimum: 1 Default: 100
-TARGET_USER_ROWS:<num> Rows Integer Minimum: 1 Default: 100
-TARGET_USER_FITS:<str> Fit Choice Available Choices: [0] nodes [1] cells Default: 0
-TARGET_TEMPLATE:<str> Target System Grid (optional input)
-TARGET_OUT_GRID:<str> Target Grid Grid (output)
-METHOD:<str> Method Choice Available Choices: [0] Linear [1] Sibson [2] Non-Sibsonian Default: 1
-WEIGHT:<double> Minimum Weight Floating point Maximum: 0.000000 Default: 0.000000

Execution completed in 2.83 seconds
Results: {'TARGET_OUT_GRID': '/private/var/folders/0v/y9l9kz9d4jsd8brqmj4z4_mr0000gn/T/processing_zaDUCh/c71189e2b98047a680f774f0920ce824/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated. 
• private/var/folders/0v/y9l9kz9d4jsd8brqmj4z4_mr0000gn/T/processing_zaDUCh/c71189e2b98047a680f774f0920ce824/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat 
• private/var/folders/0v/y9l9kz9d4jsd8brqmj4z4_mr0000gn/T/processing_zaDUCh/e3641d348d054473815617c8c049c41b/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat 
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

I've tried to change every single parameter in the natural neighbour tool, formatted the CSV to only three columns (lat/long/alt), created a shp file copy and deleted the original layer, to no avail. I always get the same error.

I am running it on a MacBook Pro Retina Early 2015 with MacOS Big Sur (11.1) installed.

I've added screenshots of the parameters and the csv file I used.

I really hope someone can help me. If not is there another way to create topographic maps from Google Earth?

Version Info:
[image: Version]

CSV table:
[image: CSV table]

After adding the CSV:
[image: After adding the CSV]

Parameters used in natural neighbour:
[image: Parameters used in natural neighbour]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to get elevation data by such a complicated detour? You could simply download freely available digital elevation models (like SRTM) - have a look at https://opendem.info/ or https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/ or https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

Comment: Where do you have the commas from in your data? Try replacing the commas with points in the file you download from http://gpsvisualizer.com. Does that help? If not, provide more information: Unfortunately, you don't write anything about what the output is when you run Natural Neighbour: an empty raster layer? None? Did you note the yellow warning message on your screenshot? Can you share your CSV?

Comment: Ready made contour lines for northern Portugal, direct link (copy the whole text until the end: 73781 and paste it manually to your browser and download the zip-archives at the bottom): https://opendem.info/opendem_client/opendem.jsp?bounds=-1051773.5090576 5065634.73781,-787607.13934078 5065634.73781,-787607.13934078 5146352.2396679,-1051773.5090576 5146352.2396679,-1051773.5090576 5065634.73781

Comment: Not sure, but [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/378824/29431) may help.